# jQuery selector to get elements without a particular sibling?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have some html that simplified looks like this:

```
<tr>
    <td><input/><span></span><i></i></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input/><span></span><i></i></td>
</tr>
    <td><input/><span></span></td>
<tr>
    <td><input/><span></span><i></td>
</tr>
```

I want to get all the spans that do not have an i sibling.

According to the jquery docs:

```
  $("div ~ p")
```

Will match all p elements that are siblings of a div element.

I can't see any way to rewrite this to get elements that do **not** have a certain sibling.

Is this possible to do with a single selector?

Thanks for any help

Edit:

Here is a jsfiddle to illustrate: http://jsfiddle.net/J6UnY/

Comment: have you tried something like `div:not(div ~ p)` and what have you tried?

Comment: You don't really have any `div`. Have you tried using the `siblings()` jQuery option

Comment: Have you even tried to search for this? questions like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11061594/get-all-elements-without-child-node-in-jquery and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14482707/jquery-selector-for-an-element-missing-a-child-element have all you need.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to select elements which do not have a specific child element with JQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7258606/how-to-select-elements-which-do-not-have-a-specific-child-element-with-jquery)

Comment: Not sure that those do answer my question. I would rather do this with a single selector, I am aware I can accomplish this programmatically. I have updated the question with a  jsfiddle.

Comment: well for starters, your `<td><input/><span></span></td>` is not wrapped in a `<tr>` tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should get you there:

```
$('td:not(:has(i))').children('span');
```